# How to substitute the bg image element with an image of my own in this tutorial

Tags: html, css

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/08/08/circle-hover-effects-with-css-transitions/

See Example 1: the author proposes that using the background image element will add freedom but when I try to implement my own image from there it doesn't appear.

Comment: It might be an image path problem. What is the path to your image and where do you keep your css and images files?

Comment: Can you post your code and directory structure?

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to answer your question without having more context, but I'm pretty sure you're encountering a path problem.

The tutorial uses a relative path under example 1. If you are also using a relative path then you should make sure the path correctly refers to the location of the file you want. You could opt to use an absolute path as well.

Relative path example: `../../images/image.png`

Absolute path example: `http://exampledomain.com/images/image.png`